# TypeError: Cannot read property 'headersSent' of undefined at headersSent (/workspace/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js:256:21)

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

express.js not working with firebase cloud function (pubsub)
iam trying to send email its working fine with pub sub function but when i  integrate express in pub sub iam getting above error

```js
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
  res.render('main', {layout : 'index'});
  console.log('succeeded')
})

exports.scheduler = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 2 minutes')
.timeZone('Asia/Karachi') // Users can choose timezone - default is America/Los_Angeles
.onRun(app)
```

Answer (score 2):

Pubsub (and scheduled) functions are not compatible with Express.  You can only use Express apps if you're writing an HTTP function.  There is no client that sends a request and receives a response, so Express is not helpful here.

If you want to use a [scheduled function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions), you should simply write code that performs the work required on schedule, then return a promise that resolves when all the async work is complete.

Comment: i want to send email using pubsub and email data is dynamic so what the best solution

Comment: did you tried to use [SendGrid?](https://sendgrid.com/). I used it with Cloud Functions in the past and it works well to generate custom emails. You can set your own custom template and fill the data dinamically.

Comment: The best solution is to just ignore Express and write the code that sends the email.  Cloud Functions doesn't have any facilities to send email, so you will need to find and integrate something to help with that.

Comment: thanks its working fine but iam not getting embeded image in email body i also tries base64 as well as cid